# Prove that two vectors are orthogonal and if not explain why.

Tags: linear-algebra

We have four vectors defined as:
$$ 
v_1=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ -2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
v_2=\begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ 0 \\ 4 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
v_3=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ -1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}
v_4=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} 
$$

Now we can form pair of two vectors from these vectors. We can form:
$$ \binom{4}{2}=6 $$
pairs if order doesn't matter. ( pairs $v_1v_2,v_2,v_1$ would count as one pair in this case.) If order does matter we would get:
$$ \binom{4}{2}2!=12 $$
possible pairs (pairs $v_1v_2,v_2v_1$ would count as two pairs.)

Problem is i dont know if order does or doesn't matter in this. Orthogonal matrix is defined as if

$$ Q^TQ=QQ^t=I $$
$$ Q^t=Q^-1 $$

So mayby it would be possible to form matrix of each pair and see if it is orthogonal or not ? Example:

$$ v_1,v_2=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 \\ 2 & 0 \\ -2 & 4 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^T=
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & -2 & 1 \\ 4 & 0 & 4 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$

When trying to calculate inverse matrix we can see that it's not possible due to the fact that matrix is not square.

If someone could provide some insight how do you calculate if two vectors are orthogonal or not that would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Tuki

Comment: i would calculate the dot-product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $v_1^Tv_2 = v_2^Tv_1$, hence order doesn't matter.

Examine if $v_i^Tv_j = 0$ if $i \neq j$, if so the vectors are orthogonal to each other.

We can also form the matrix $Q = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2 & v_3 & v_4\end{bmatrix}$ and check if $Q^TQ=D$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix, if you get a diagonal matrix, then any two vectors are orthogonal

Note: A matrix is orthogonal if it is a square matrix and its columns are orthonormal.

Comment: Diagonal you mean that there are non zero values in diagonal slots of matrix and else where it's zero ?. Example $$ D=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 8 \end{bmatrix}  $$ would be considered as $D$ ? And if we get $Q^TQ=D$ then what does this tell us then ?

Comment: if you get a diagonal matrix, then the vectors are orthogonal to each other. It doesn't mean the matrix is an orthogonal matrix though. Orthogonal matrix requires the vectors to be orthonormal, if it is an orthogonal matrix, you will get the identity matrix. If the columns are just orthogonal to each other, you should get a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Scalar product of two vectors can be calculated either as: $$|a|*|b|*cos(\alpha)$$ or as $$a_1*b_1+a_2*b_2+...$$

Vectors are orthogonal iff $cos(\alpha)=0$.

So, it's very easy to check if two vectors are orthogonal, just calculate scalar product. F.e. $(v_1, v_2) = 1*4 + 2*0 - 2*4 + 1*0 = -4$. Not zero => vectors are not orthogonal.